# How to implement !! for Integer in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm new in Haskell programming. I'm in search for an implementation of `!!` operator which I need to use not as `[a] -> Int -> a` or `[a] -> Int -> [a]`
but as `[a] -> Integer -> [a]`, or `[a] -> Integer -> a`.

Some code where I want to use this:

```
next x = 1: zipWith (+) x (tail x) ++ [1]
bins :: Integer -> [Integer]
bins n
  | n < 0 = undefined
  | otherwise = (( (foldr (:) [] $ unfoldr (\st->Just(st,next st)) [1]) !! n ))
```

And i can't just change type of `bins :: Integer -> [Integer]` to `bins :: Int -> [Integer]`
because it's a strict condition in tests.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to use `!!`. It is _certainly_ a bad idea to use a version of it generalised to `Integer`. A list that's so big that it can't be indexed with `Int` can't possibly fit in memory, and it would take ages (literally).

Comment: [The documentation for `Data.List.genericIndex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericIndex) has a “source” button, but that’s also probably something you should be able to implement on your own before jumping into more complicated things like this.

Comment: Too much parenthesis: ` (foldr (:) [] $ unfoldr (\st->Just (st,next st)) [1]) !! n`

Comment: `foldr (:) []` is the identity on lists. Since it's immediately applied to a list, I'd simply remove that from your code.

Comment: Exactly what is `bins` supposed to do? Convert an `Integer` to a list of zeros and ones? In that case, you do not need `!!`.

Comment: It looks like `bins` is supposed to represent a line of the pascal triangle, name might be bins like binomials. @Лев Кореньков, you are supposed to include that information in your question!

Comment: @leftaroundabout If you want to set a new record for digits of pi found, you'll need a bigger integer than `!!` allows.

Comment: Okay, so... what's your question? When you tried to implement `(!!)`, what did you write, what went wrong, and why do you feel stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call it through `fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b` like so:

```
  ..... !! (fromIntegral n)
```

and keep your type signature as is, because `Integer` is an `Integral` type and `Int` is a `Num`.

In GHCi,

```
> fromIntegral (1::Integer)::Int
1
it :: Int

> :i Integral
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
 ....
instance Integral Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
instance Integral Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'

> :i Num
class Num a where
 ....
instance Num Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
instance Num Int -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
....
```

Of course this can introduce the usual integer wrap-around problems,

```
> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807
it :: Int

> (maxBound :: Int) + 1
-9223372036854775808
it :: Int

> (fromIntegral (maxBound :: Int) :: Integer) + 1
9223372036854775808
it :: Integer

> (fromIntegral (fromIntegral (maxBound :: Int) :: Integer) + 1) :: Int
-9223372036854775808
```

But it is *probably* safe to assume you won't actually use it with such high index values, *ever*.